# jqGrid cell formatter property

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to update formatter on a single cell of a column dynamically. I'm able to change the formatter for the entire column using

> $(jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('setColProp', 'colName', {formatter: ''})).trigger('reloadGrid')

However when I use code below the grid refreshes but with no changes.

> $(jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('setCell', j, 'colName', '','',{formatter: ''})).trigger('reloadGrid')

Answer (score 1):

No, the formatter is for the whole column, not a single cell. If you need this level of granularity, you will need to use a custom formatter function with logic that can somehow detect that you are in that particular cell - such as by using the row object to get the row ID.